# Online user status on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanna know how to change online user status when the user login. I have been looking for this but there is no answer for my question. I'm new on learning this codeigniter so, I wish you guys could help for my problem, please.

Controller:

```
public function signdevice() {
    $device = $this->input->post('device');
    $pass = $this->input->post('password');
    $data = array(
        'device'   => $device,
        'password' => $pass,
        'status'   => $status
    );
    $status = 1;
    $res = $this->db->get_where('devices', $data);
    if ($res->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->session->set_userdata(
            array(
                'signin' => TRUE,
                'device' => $device,
                'status' => $status
            )
        );
        $data = array('device' => $device, 'password' => $pass, 'status' => 1);
        $this->db->where('device', '$device');
        $this->db->update('devices', $data);
        redirect(base_url('pelanggan'));
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('result_login', 'Wrong Username or Password.');
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

Models:

```
function login($user,$pass)
{
    $this->db->where('device', $user);
    $this->db->where('password', $pass);
    $query = $this->db->get('devices');
    if($query->num_rows()==1) {
        return $query->row_array();
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Username atau password salah!');
        redirect('login');
    }
}

function update($id,$stat)
{
    $data['status'] = $stat;
    $stat = 1;
    $this->db->where('kd_device', $id);
    $this->db->update('devices', $stat);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Apart from not specifically initialising $status = 0, what you have should work? So what is the actual issue you have with your code? What makes you think its not working.

Answer (score 2):

You have several line of missing & misplaced code.

Controller :

```
public function signdevice() {
    $device = $this->input->post('device');
    $pass = $this->input->post('password');
    $data = array(
        'device'   => $device,
        'password' => $pass,
        'status'   => 0 // changed value to 0
    );
    $status = 1;
    $res = $this->db->get_where('devices', $data);
    if ($res->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->session->set_userdata(
            array(
                'signin' => TRUE,
                'device' => $device,
                'status' => $status
            )
        );
        $data = array('device' => $device, 'password' => $pass, 'status' => 1);
        $this->db->where('device', $device); // removed quotes
        $this->db->update('devices', $data);
        redirect(base_url('pelanggan'));
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('result_login', 'Wrong Username or Password.');
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

Model :

```
...
function update($id,$stat)
{
    $stat = 1; // swapped this line with below
    $data['status'] = $stat; // swapped this line with above
    $this->db->where('kd_device', $id);
    $this->db->update('devices', $data); // maybe what you want to save is $data?
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Funny thing is, the model with update() is never used.